# Error during model fit in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

When I am trying to fit my model on X_train and y_train, it gives me an error as shown in the image. The term Alberta is one of the entry in the province column of the dataset. Here i am using Decision Tree and Random forest as it is an unbalanced dataset. Please help me to resolve this error. I don't know where am i going wrong..
[image]

Comment: To train, all values in `X_train` or `y_train` must be `float` or `int`. In your case, it is not. If you add code block with some samples of data, contributors can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably happens because you have both numerical values and strings in the dataset.
Some solutions I would suggest are:

- Go through the dataset and drop unnecessary features/columns (be careful that you won't drop important features).
- [Convert the categorical type columns into numeric](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-categorical/) to get rid of strings.